# SVG full Width, while keeping img proportions

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, viewbox

I've got an svg image which I want to autoresize to 100% width. 
The problem is, that I've placed an Image (100px x 100px) on the left side of that svg and that picture has to keep its proportions.

I tried it with viewBox, but with this method the whole svg, and not only the path, gets resized.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
 <g>
  <title>title</title>
  <image x="0" y="1.00001" width="100" height="100" id="svg_1" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
  <path style="-webkit-user-select: auto;" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" d="m98.66982,67.61566c0,0 136.5026,-1.32306 303.78312,-30.42615c167.28064,-29.10306 238.87799,-14.55161 238.20886,-14.55161c-0.66913,0 1.33826,79.37253 1.33826,79.37253c0,0 -543.33026,1.32291 -543.99939,1.32291c-0.66912,0 0.66915,-35.71768 0.66915,-35.71768z" id="svg_10"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

For using the svg I've got

```
<div class="svg">
    <p>tesygst</p>
</div>
```

and

```
.svg {
  background: url(pathToSvg.svg) no-repeat bottom left;
  position : fixed;
  bottom : 0;
  left : 0;
  height : 100px;
  width : 100%;
}
```

The img has to be placed at the left bottom corner, while the path has to extend itself to 100% width starting at the end of that pic.

Hope somebody can help me :/

Comment: [This article](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) can likely explain your issues more than a short answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put an image inside an SVG, stretch the SVG and have the image not stretch also.  That's just how things work.  You have to think of the contents of the SVG just the same as if you were talking about an `<img>` rather than an SVG.  You stretch the img, the whole thing stretches.

I take it you are trying to keep the image at 100x100px?

You will need to move the image out of the SVG and into the HTML.  Then position it in the right place with CSS.  For example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
 <g>
  <title>title</title>
  <path style="-webkit-user-select: auto;" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" d="m98.66982,67.61566c0,0 136.5026,-1.32306 303.78312,-30.42615c167.28064,-29.10306 238.87799,-14.55161 238.20886,-14.55161c-0.66913,0 1.33826,79.37253 1.33826,79.37253c0,0 -543.33026,1.32291 -543.99939,1.32291c-0.66912,0 0.66915,-35.71768 0.66915,-35.71768z" id="svg_10"/>
 </g>
</svg>

<img width="100" height="100" src="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
```

CSS:

```
IMG {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rcdx4qnh/2/)